# ERRORLEVEL not reporting correctly

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, errorlevel

I am running the below windows .bat script which I am having trouble with.

```
@echo off
set /p Var1= Drag and drop your .itmsp folder here: 

CALL C:\progra~2\itms\iTMSTransporter -m verify -f %Var1% -u username -p password -o %Var1%\log.txt -s shortname -v eXtreme WONoPause true

IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto PASS
else goto FAIL

:PASS
blat c:\temp\file.txt -to user@example.com -subject "This has passed"
exit

:FAIL
blat c:\temp\file.txt -to user@example.com -subject "This has failed"
exit
```

The command runs but ERRORLEVEL does not seem to work, only reports 0, nothing else. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Here's an update. The errorlevel is not retuning anything other than 0

Comment: Sorry, changed the question to reflect where I am now.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you don't need the start command. The IF-ELSE syntax is wrong but you actually don't need the else part. And I would bet that you need to quote the parameters. Try this:

```
@echo off
set /p Var1= Drag and drop your .itmsp folder here: 

CALL C:\progra~2\itms\iTMSTransporter -m verify -f "%Var1%" -u username -p password -o "%Var1%\log.txt" -s shortname -v eXtreme WONoPause true

rem fail if ERRORLEVEL >= 1 otherwise continue
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto FAIL

blat c:\temp\file.txt -to user@example.com -subject "This has passed"
goto:EOF

:FAIL
blat c:\temp\file.txt -to user@example.com -subject "This has failed"
```

Comment: Sorry TomT, this doesn't work. Neither of the blat commands execute.

Comment: I believe the clue is in "The command runs in a separate window" - `iTMSTransporter` would seem to be a batch file and hence the `call` is required otherwise execution is transferrred to the target with no return point. This would also explain why **neither** of the `blat` commands was reached.

Comment: no error messages, command still runs, then window closes, neither blat commands execute.

Comment: Sorry, got it wrong. The command now runs, it returns 1 (fail), but ERRORLEVEL reports incorrectly to be 0.

Comment: what do you mean by "it returns 1 (fail)"? if ERRORLEVEL is 0 how is 1 returned? is it printed out?

Comment: When transporter application runs in command window it displays lots of info, when if finishes it displays either a 0 (pass) or 1 (fail).

Comment: well. the obvious question is, does the transporter application set ERRORLEVEL? I guess not.